# Removing a large number files from svn 1.7

Tags: svn

Im using Windows 8 and subversion 1.7 I accidently added a folder to a folder under svn control, and all the contents are marked as new in SmartSVN. I tried reverting the files but because there are some 70,000 files it just hangs. Even if I delete the folder SmartSVN still thinks they exist

So I know there is a root .svn folder which can be deleted but I just want to delete the entries referring to this folder rather than all the valid subversion references.

Actually it make me wonder why they changed from having a suversion folder per folder to just having one folder, it would be easy to resolve this with the older format.

Comment: Do the revert in batches. Yes, it is tedious, but would avoid the SmartSVN hanging issue

Comment: You could selectively commit any local changes you do not want to lose, then simply delete your local checkout and do another checkout.

Comment: @Josh I did what you said, and that worked so problem solved, although I still wonder oif it could be done by modifying .svn